# Logstash filtering, Using custom grok filters

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

How can I use multi defined patterns in grok filter?
here is my logstash.conf file content.

`grok {
        match => { "message" => "(?<statusCode>(__ %{NONNEGINT} __) +) 
                                 (?<test>%{INT})"}
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 3 hours, I figured out how to fix it.
The config file should be look like this.

```
 grok {
     match => { "message" => "(?<action>-- %{WORD} --)"}
 }
 grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{URIPATHPARAM:requestUri}" }
 }
```